# its possible to solve using backtracking?

Tags: algorithm

I choose this solution teeth in each row select any number.
If you choose the number of row x1 and column y1, I can not choose another number of  row x1 and column y1, I must in each row and column select one number so that the sum of these numbers as small as possible

```
 1 2 3 1
 2 3 1 3
 2 2 1 2
 3 4 1 9
```

my function generates only one solution which is not optimal namely:

```
 1* 2 3 1
 2 3* 1 3
 2 2 1* 2
 3 4 1  9*
```

but the best solution is to:

```
 1 2 3 1*
 2 3 1* 3
 2* 2 1 2
 3 1* 1 9
```

what I need to change in my function? I can not find the solution of two days
help me I will be grateful

```
bool back(int n, r ** tab, int k){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (check(n,tab,k)){
            tab[k][i].moze=true;
            if (k==n-1)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
                    {
                        if(tab[j][k].moze==true)
                            cout<<tab[j][i].quantity;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (back(n,tab,k+1))
                return true;
            else

                tab[k][i].moze=false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**someone help me solve for you, it's probably The question of a few minutes I get tired already 5 days**

Comment: It's very unclear what the algorithm is supposed to do, even with your examples (one of them has a typo, no?). Methinks rewrite the question and include a great deal more details.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear.  When you say "the smallest number of columns", do you mean "the smallest number in each column"?  But I think there must be other constraints that you aren't telling us about, because that is very easy to solve -- just treat each column independently.

Comment: I choose this solution teeth in each row select any number.
If you choose the number of row x1 and column y1, I can not choose another number of  row x1 and column y1, I must in each row and column select one number so that the sum of these numbers as small as possible

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question with the exact same input yesterday.

Comment: @Kunal I've seen this question twice before...

Answer (score -1):

Backtracking is used when you want to find a solution, not when you want to find the optimal solution. When you reach a position in the decision tree where you can't continue, you backtrack and pick a different choice in an earlier solution. In your case, the normal approach is to just test every permutation of in turn, which makes it O(n!)-expensive.

Now, you can still use something similar to backtracking which will be educational: For every partial solution, you rule out all those that can't possibly improve on the best result. That way, you will cut off whole branches of the decision tree. Using a greedy algorithm to find a good solution as first step helps with this approach. The problem is that this isn't going to make your algorithm much faster though, because you still have to walk large parts of the tree before you *know* that you have the best solution. It's still interesting though.

If you want to practice backtracking, try a sodoku solver. ;)

Comment: that is, one can not resolve this task by Bactracking?

Comment: -1: EVERY task that can be solved by a computer can be solved by backtracking search.  That's because every computable problem can be modeled as a search on a (usually implicitly-defined) graph.  BTW the name for the concept your 2nd paragraph refers to is "branch and bound", and yes it's a valuable approach to tackling problems for which no more efficient solution is known (e.g. NP-hard problems).

Comment: While we're in a nitpicking contest here, I didn't write that backtracking can't be used but that it isn't used. *sigh*

Comment: You claim that backtracking is not used when you want to find an optimal solution.  But that's just not true.